# python timeout for command execution if it is not completed in 5 seconds

Tags: python, python-2.7

what is the best way to add  timeout  for command if unable to complete in 5 seconds.

```
from subprocess import check_output
try:
    check_output("dh")
except Notexecuted:
    print"command not successful executed"
```

Version=python2.7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Timeout on a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call)

Answer (score 0):

In python 2.7 we don't have a directly implemented timeout function with subprocess. Instead I suggest `subprocess32` package.

```
from subprocess32 import Popen, PIPE

cmd = "<your command>"
response = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = response.communicate(timeout=5)
```

( In python 3.x we have this timeout param with default `subprocess`)

PS: Refer the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html).

> POSIX users (Linux, BSD, etc.) are strongly encouraged to install and
>   use the much more recent subprocess32 module instead of the version
>   included with python 2.7. It is a drop in replacement with better
>   behavior in many situations.

Hope this Help!